# Hazelcast is using high number of JVM threads

Tags: jvm, hazelcast, distributed-caching

I am using hazelcast in JVM in my application which is running 2 replicas in kubernetes. Hazelcast in both comtainers has formed a cluster and sync is working perfectly fine.

But my application has started using 20% more threads after starting to using hazelcast. On aanalyzing thread dump it is found that hazelcast is using that extra 20%

[image]

Is it okay for hazelcast to use this many number of threads or if this can be reduced, how can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast will self-size the number of threads it uses, based on the number of processors available to it.

(In Java, see [Runtime.availableProcessors()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--) )

How many does your container have allocated ?

You can override the threading if you are sure it's inappropriate. Look for system properties like `hazelcast.*.thread.count` from [here](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/system-properties.html). There are many options and it's not a casual task just to reduce or increase, If you tune numbers down, you risk performance being very poor.